# How to call an ASP web api and return JSON from delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-2007

I need to call to an ASP web api and return JSON from delphi 2007. I'm able to do it in RAD Studio XE 5 with TRestClient. I was trying to put it in a dll so that I can call it from my delphi 2007 program. But no success. How can I do this using delphi 2007?

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm trying to do in delphi xe 5

```
class function TSampleApp.Hello(AModel: TModel): Integer;
var
  aRestClient: TRESTClient;
  aRestRequest: TRESTRequest;
  aRestResponse: TRESTResponse;
  aParam: TRESTRequestParameter;     
  jValue: TJSONValue;
  jObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  Result := -1;
  aRestClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  try
    aRestResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
    try
      aRestRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
      try
        try          
          aRestClient.BaseURL := 'http://localhost:49272/api/test';
          aRestRequest.Client := aRestClient;
          aRestRequest.Response := aRestResponse;
          aRestRequest.Method := rmPOST;
          aRestRequest.Resource := 'hello';
          aParam := aRestRequest.Params.AddItem;
          aParam.Kind := pkREQUESTBODY;
          aParam.name := 'helloData';
          aParam.Value := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(AModel);

          aRestRequest.Execute;

          jValue := aRestResponse.JSONValue;
          jObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jValue.ToString) as TJSONObject;
          Result := StrToIntDef((jObject.Get('status').JsonValue as TJSONString).Value, -1);
        finally
          FreeAndNil(jObject);
          FreeAndNil(jValue);
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(aRestRequest);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(aRestResponse);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(aRestClient);
  end;
end;
```

This code runs perfectly in win32 app, but fail on "aRestResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);" when put into a dll.

Comment: What exactly did you try?  What exactly did not work for you?  You need to provide specific details if you want help with it.

Comment: Indy should work well - you'll just need to parse the JSON with the Superobjects Lib or similar. Drop TIDHTTP component on form or instantiate it -> str := TIDHTTP.get(**resturl***)

Comment: @Remy Sorry for the late reply. I updated my question with sample code.

Comment: @Ryno That's what i did, and it worked :)

Comment: an up vote on the comment would be nice :)

Comment: @ryno upvoted your comment. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find rest client solution for delphi 2007. I end up using indy for this.
I use [LkJson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/) to handle json.

```
class function TSampleApp.Hello(AModel: TModel): Integer;
var
  idHttp: TIdHTTP;
  url, sjsonresponse, sjsonrequest: string;
  strRequest: TStrings;
  jsonObj: TlkJSONobject;
begin
  Result := -1;
  url := 'http://localhost:49272/api/test/hello';
  idHttp := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    jsonObj := TlkJSONobject.Create;
    try
      //populate
      jsonObj.Add('param1', AModel.param1);
      jsonObj.Add('param2', AModel.param2);
      sjsonrequest := TlkJSON.GenerateText(jsonObj);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(jsonObj);
    end;

    idHttp.Request.Accept := 'application/json';   
    strRequest := TStringList.Create;
    try
      strRequest.Values['helloData'] := sjsonrequest;
      sjsonresponse := idHttp.Post(url, strRequest);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(strRequest);
    end;

    jsonObj := TlkJSON.ParseText(sjsonresponse) as TlkJSONobject;
    try
      Result := StrToIntDef(VarToStr((jsonObj.Field['status'] as TlkJSONnumber).Value), -1);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(jsonObj);
    end;
  finally
    idHttp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This code works also inside a dll.